# Bounding box not right rotation XNA blender object (.fbx)

Tags: xna, c#, blender, fbx

I am importing .fbx models (a simple cuboid), the model itself displays fine (and is repeated to make a wall) however the bounding box seems to be on the wrong rotation. Below is a screen shoot:

[image]

The yellow line is the bounding box for the grey cuboids.

The map walls are loaded from a map object that specifies where walls should be

```
for (int row = 0; row < map.Rows; row++){
                for (int col = 0; col < map.Columns; col++){
                    if (map.Get(row, col) == 'w') walls.Add(new Wall(content.Load<Model>("models/wallnew"), new Vector3(col, 0, row)));
                }
            }
```

and a wall is:

```
public class Wall : Entity {
        BoundingBox boundingBox;

        public Wall(Model model, Vector3 position) : base(model){
            this.translation = Matrix.CreateTranslation(position);
            Vector3 from = Vector3.Transform(new Vector3(0f), World);
            Vector3 to = Vector3.Transform(new Vector3(1f), World);
            boundingBox = new BoundingBox(from, to);
        }

        public BoundingBox GetBoundingBox() {
            return boundingBox;
        }

        public override void Draw(bool textured, Matrix view, Matrix proj) {
            foreach (ModelMesh mesh in model.Meshes) {
                foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects) {
                    effect.World = World * mesh.ParentBone.Transform;
                    effect.View = view;
                    effect.Projection = proj;
                    effect.EnableDefaultLighting();
                }
                mesh.Draw();
            }
        }
    }
```

I cant for the life of me work out why the bounding box is being added wrong, if you need any more info let me know!

Comment: I'm not sure if this is associated with your problem, but try changing this:

    `effect.World = World * mesh.ParentBone.Transform;`

to this since Xna uses Row major Matrices:

    `effect.World = mesh.ParentBone.Transform * World;`

Comment: @SteveH thanks however still having the same issue